# Paypal recurring in Rails - If the user changes plan, How to change the subscription amount it in paypal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paypal

I have am selling a product and the user has 2 options, Plan A with $1 per month and plan B with $2/month. I am using paypal recurring on my rails app, something like shown in railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/289-paypal-recurring-billing

I am using devise for user management and authentication and have Plan model with 2 values. Now I want to have feature where the user can migrate from one plan to another.

I can do

```
#registration_controller.rb

change_plan
  if current_user.plan_id == 1
    current_user.plan_id = 2
  elsif current_user.plan_id = 2
    current_user.plan_id = 1
  end
  current_user.save
end
```

Is this code correct ? also this will only change the user plan in User model but I don't think this will change the paypal subscription and recurring amount ($1 to $2), how to do this since I am not able to find much info on this on web.

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out?